# Add javascript variable to addDomListener

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to pass a javascript variable to addDomListener to trigger a googlemaps function.

If I write:

```
    var name=a1;

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(name, 'mouseover', function() {
```

It works.

But if I write:

```
    var i=1;
    var name="a"+i;
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(name, 'mouseover', function() {
```

It doesnt work.
But:

```
    alert(name)
```

gives me

```
    a1
```

in both cases.

I can't figure out whats the problem!

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Ok, in more details:

I am generating multiple div names, each one corresponding to a different event.
Here is the HTML/PHP:

```
    <?php
    $i=0;
    foreach ($key as $name)
    {  ?>

    <div class="row">
     <ul class="event-list">
       <li >
           <img "src="images/image.jpg" />
             <div  id="a<?=$i?>" style="min-height: 120px;min-width: 120px;" class="info">
             <h2 class="title"><?= $name ?></h2>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <?php $i++; } ?>
```

So for example I have divs: a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5

Mouseover these divs have to modify the icon color of the associated Marker on google-maps.
Here is the script:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">


    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?= json_encode($lat); ?>, <?= json_encode($lng);?>),
        zoom: <?php echo json_encode(13); ?>,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;



      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("map_controller.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          //var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var image = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';
          


          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: image


          });
        
          hover(marker,i);
   
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
          
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        
      });
    }

     
    function hover(marker,i){
    
 var name=a0; //ok
 //var name="a"+i; //doesnt work in addDomListener
    alert(name);
    
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(name, 'mouseover', function() {
    marker.setIcon('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png');
 return i;
    
 });
   }
  

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }


</script>
```

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't work"? Which error returns?

Comment: Sorry. Console gives : TypeError: c is undefined. Also, I am looping from i=1 to 5 and it stops after 1 in the case var i=1 ... compare to var name=a1;

Comment: Please create http://jsfiddle.net or similar. Without it we can only guess.

Comment: where is c in your code .. show the content of the function too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is far from what the real meaning with the question is, but I'll give it a try anyway : You cannot attach DomListeners to strings, you can attach listeners to instances (like a `map`) or DOM element references.

If you have a marker, you can enrich that marker with all sorts of variables :

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position : new google.maps.LatLng(56.05, 10.4),
   map : map,
   someVariable : 'hello' 
});
```

and then retrieve those variables upon an event :

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
   alert(this.someVariable)
});
```

a small demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zvfqd04q/**

---

**Update**. As written above, you cannot attach a handler to a string. After seeing your code in the updated question I can see you not need google maps `addDomListener` either. Simply attach a native `onmouseover` event handler (or similar) to the a+n `<div>` elements.

Example with some `<div>`'s and a modified `hover()` function. Each `<div>` is bound to a `marker` which icon is changed if you hold the mouse over that corresponding `<div>` or move the mouse away from the `<div>` :

```
function hover(marker, i){
    document.getElementById('a'+i).onmouseover = function() {
       marker.setIcon('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png');
    }
    document.getElementById('a'+i).onmouseleave = function() {
       marker.setIcon('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png');
    }
}
```

as in your code :

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   map: map,
   position: point,
   icon: image
});
hover(marker,i);
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qz5ggzry/**

Comment: This is to good to be true :) Thank you so much for your help.